# Creating objects dynamically in javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi trying to create this array dynamically. This is the static way:

```
var pieData = [
                {
                    value: 300,
                    color:getRandomColor(),
                    highlight: getRandomColor(),
                },
                {
                    value: 50,
                    color: getRandomColor(),
                    highlight: "#fac878",
                },
                {
                    value: 100,
                    color: getRandomColor(),
                    highlight: getRandomColor(),
                },
                {
                    value: 120,
                    color: getRandomColor(),
                    highlight: getRandomColor(),
                }

            ];
```

This is what I achieved:

```
$.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "getPieChartData"
    })
    .done(function(data){
        obj  = $.parseJSON(data);
        var pieData = []; i = 0;
        $.each(obj, function(key, item) {
            pieData[i].value = item.total + " - " + item.d_name;
            pieData[i].color = getRandomColor();
            pieData[i].highlight = getRandomColor();
            i++;
        });
    });
```

I am getting value from my function that is not a problem. My issue is that I am getting in the console that this part:

```
pieData[i].value = item.total +" - " + item.d_name; TypeError: pieData[i] is undefined
```

What am I doing wrong? thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simple use [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method. No meed to use indexer.

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

```
$.each(obj, function(key, item) {
    pieData.push({
        value: item.total + " - " + item.d_name,
        color : getRandomColor(),
        highlight : getRandomColor()
    });
});
```

Comment: but how can I access after the ajax event ? if I put a console log it said me that is undefined ?

Comment: @GeorgeMoldovan,  __A__ of AJAX  stands for asynchronous go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call , Its a good read and will provide solution for your problem

Comment: This code works good, but "push" isn't the solution of the problem. The solution IS the new object passed to push, but you can do it without push too, like @James Newton wrote in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the pieData[i] object first;

```
var pieData = []; i = 0;
$.each(obj, function(key, item) {
    pieData[i] = {}; // added line
    pieData[i].value = item.total + " - " + item.d_name;
    pieData[i].color = getRandomColor();
    pieData[i].highlight = getRandomColor();
    i++;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Before `pieData[i].value ..`, you should first have a line:

```
pieData[i] = {};
```